# OGR_STYLE label style line breaks

Tags: gdal, ogr, geospatial-pdf

I am trying to create a GeoSpatial PDF using gdal_translate.

Using the vrt file i am able to generate OGRFeatures having STYLE

OGRFeature():23
OGR_STYLE (String) = SYMBOL(id:"icn_cabinet_external.png",s:0);LABEL(f:"Arial, Helvetica", c:#FF0000, bo:1, m:w, dp:1px, p:10, dx:-10, dy:10, s:10px, t:{label})

My requirement is to put a linebreak in the label for which i tried adding \n but it doesn't seems to work.
LABEL (String) = FIRST PART \n  SECOND PART

Does OGR_STYLE supports line breaks ?

Comment: I believe that OGR_STYLE stores just a string and it is up to the rendering party how it interprets some special character combinations inside the string. It seems that also other software has had troubles with multiline labels in PDF https://groups.google.com/g/pdfnet-webviewer/c/_6eM4kfKez4. PDF in GDAL is also not always the same but the PDF library matters (Poppler, PoDoFo, PDFium) and it seems that PDF driver supports OGR_STYLES only partially https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pdf.html. Maybe you should write mail to gdal-dev mailing list.